# Animate text change using JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

```js
   (() => {
   const pEle = document.querySelector('#animated-text');
   const spanEle = pEle.querySelector('span');
   const words = JSON.parse(spanEle.dataset.words);
   let count = 0;  

 setInterval(function(){
         spanEle.innerHTML = words[count];
         if (count < words.length - 1) count = count + 1;
         else count = 0;
 }, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) * 1000);

})();
```

```html
<style>
#animated-text span {
  color: red;
}
</style>

<p id="animated-text">
       Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known,
       <span data-words='["One", "Two", "Three"]'>Default
       </span>
       is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. 
</p>
```

### I would like to use JS and CSS to do some animation like below. I cannot hardcode animation duration in css.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want something already done : [animate.style](https://animate.style/)

Look at the "slideInUp". You have just to play with the class to get the animation that you want. And you can add some code to modifiy them, if you want.

The Github Project : [animate.css](https://github.com/animate-css/animate.css)